# Microsoft Azure EventHub Exception: The handle 'XX' is already associated with object 'sessionXYZ'

Tags: .net, azure, azure-eventhub

I have a .net client that receives data from Microsoft Azure Eventhub. At times, my receiver throws this exception 'Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventHubsException: The handle 'XX' is already associated with object 'sessionXYZ'  at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpPartitionReceiver.d__13.MoveNext().

I am unable to identify the cause of this issue as this error comes up at quite random time. I verified if there is any data loss, but I haven't found any data loss as well.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue and if there is a possible data loss because of this as well.

Comment: Can you help us understand what type you're using as a receiver (is it the `PartitionReceiver` or another something else) and how you're configuring the receiver?   It would also be helpful to understand what other event consumers are running against the same Event Hub.

Comment: Regardless, because events are never removed from a partition, there's no chance of data loss so long as you're not explicitly creating a checkpoint to a later event.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you running? What is the operation timeout set for the client?

Comment: @JesseSquire basically I have an event hub and for each partition of the event hub, I start a new thread in which I use eventhub client to create a receiver for that partition. Then in this thread, I call ReceiveAsync() method to read new events rom eventhub. I have three services that are consuming events from the same eventhub in parallel. As I mentioned, this issue only occurs occasionally so I am not sure what causes it.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I am using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs v3.0.0. I don't think I have explicitly set timeout for client in the application.

Comment: @GAli:  Seeing a code sample for exactly how you're creating/configuring your `EventHubClient` and `PartitionReceiver` would be helpful.